# wordpress ajax-admin.php aborted on mozilla, works on chrome

Tags: javascript, ajax, wordpress, mozilla, apache2.4

I am having real problems with mozilla to show corectly masonry grid gallery on frontend.

While Chrome loads photos corectly through admin-ajax.php mozilla won't.

Here is my page.
EDITED OUT as its not needed anymore.

when you open it in chrome its fine and working no problems all admin-ajax.php posts get responses and loaded fine.

In mozilla I found that admin-ajax.php says ABORTED on the requests but can't find reason why.
POST admin-ajax.php Aborted xxxxx.cz 0 B xx.xx.xx.xx:443

Can anyone help me to find why firefox aborting those requests ?

EDIT:
Found maybe source of the problem but don't know how to fix it.
In firefox I was able to modify header of the request and I did find that Firefox is not sending parameter ACCEPT LANGUAGE correctly.

Accept-Language: cs,en-US,cs;q=0.8,en;q=0.6

But chrome sending language correctly
Accept-Language: cs-CZ,cs;q=0.8,en;q=0.6

I did modify header in firefox to cs-CZ and since then firefox did receive response from apache.

So question now is how to make Firefox to send correct language for accept language or how to make server to send him response even on en-US request ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was problem with mod_spdy and php5 module in apache2.

Fixed it with disabling php5 mod and enabled mod_fcgid instead according to this article.

https://developers.google.com/speed/spdy/mod_spdy/php